# Custom pixel Woocommerce integration via google tag manager or via php

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, tags, google-tag-manager

Good evening i have a Woocommerce e-shop and i would like to integrate a custom pixel code of an affiliate site to track some events of the products like page view, category view, purchase made and more. The code they would me to integrate in my website is the following code and instructions:

**PageView Code:**

```
<script>
(function(f, a, s, h, i, o, n) {f['GlamiTrackerObject'] = i;
f[i]=f[i]||function(){(f[i].q=f[i].q||[]).push(arguments)};o=a.createElement(s),
n=a.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];o.async=1;o.src=h;n.parentNode.insertBefore(o,n)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.glami.gr/js/compiled/pt.js', 'glami');

glami('create', '5A5E5996B2A69C196F8C4BC9E7E55F41', 'gr');
glami('track', 'PageView');
</script>
```

**ViewContent (product):**

```
glami('track', 'ViewContent', {
content_type: 'product',
item_ids: ['ADZXFLUX002'], // currently viewed product ID. Use the same ID as you use in the feed (ITEM_ID)
product_names: ['Adidas ZX Flux Power Red'] // currently viewed product name. Use the same names as you use in the feed (PRODUCTNAME).
});
```

**ViewContent (category):**

```
glami('track', 'ViewContent', {
content_type: 'category',
item_ids: ['ADZXFLUX001', 'NRS02', 'NRS03', 'NRS04', 'NRS05', 'NRS06', 'NRS07', 'NRS08', 'NRS09', 'NRS10'], // currently viewed first 10 product IDs in the category. Use the same IDs as you use in the feed (ITEM_ID).
product_names: ['Adidas ZX Flux Power Red', 'Nike running shorts', ...] // currently viewed first 10 product names. Use the same names as you use in the feed (PRODUCTNAME).
category_id: 'ID_SHOES_001' // currently viewed category ID. Use the same category ID as you use in the feed (CATEGORY_ID)
category_text: 'Men | Shoes | Sneakers' // currently viewed category_text. Use the same category_text as you use in the feed (CATEGORYTEXT)
});
```

**AddToCart**

```
glami('track', 'AddToCart', {
item_ids: ['ADZXFLUX002'], // product ID currently added to a cart. Use the same ID as you use in the feed (ITEM_ID).
product_names: ['Adidas ZX Flux Power Red'], // product name currently added to a cart. Use the same names as you use in the feed (PRODUCTNAME).
value: 2495.00, // product price
currency: 'EUR' // product price currency
});
```

**Purchase:**

```
glami('track', 'Purchase', {
item_ids: ['ADZXFLUX002', 'NRS01'], // bought product IDs. Use the same IDs as you use in the feed (ITEM_ID).
product_names: ['Adidas ZX Flux Power Red', 'Nike running shorts'], // bought product names. Use the same names as you use in the feed (PRODUCTNAME).
value: 3490.00, // order value
currency: 'EUR', // order value currency
transaction_id: 'ORDER212' // order ID
});
```

i am interested to integrate the code via Google Tag Manager or via php on the theme php function file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use Hooks for that. For most of the codes it's pretty simple, but for add to cart it's a bit more complex.

**PageView Code**

```
add_action('wp_footer', 'glami_pageview_code');
function glami_pageview_code(){
?>
    <script>
(function(f, a, s, h, i, o, n) {f['GlamiTrackerObject'] = i;
f[i]=f[i]||function(){(f[i].q=f[i].q||[]).push(arguments)};o=a.createElement(s),
n=a.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];o.async=1;o.src=h;n.parentNode.insertBefore(o,n)
})(window, document, 'script', '//www.glami.gr/js/compiled/pt.js', 'glami');

glami('create', '5A5E5996B2A69C196F8C4BC9E7E55F41', 'gr');
glami('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<?php
}
```

**ViewContent (product)**

```
add_action('woocommerce_before_single_product', 'glami_pageview_single_product_code');
function glami_pageview_single_product_code(){
global $product;
$product_id = $product->get_id();
?>
  <script>
glami('track', 'ViewContent', {
content_type: 'product',
item_ids: ['<?php echo $product_id; ?>'], 
product_names: ['<?php echo $product->get_title(); ?>'] 
});
</script>
<?php
}
```

**ViewContent (Category)**

same way, the hook name is 'woocommerce_archive_description', (here you gonna have some work if they want you to list all product IDs). So it will look like this

```
add_action('woocommerce_archive_description', 'glami_pageview_product_code');
function glami_pageview_product_cat_code(){ ...
```

**Purchase...** same way, just different hook

```
add_action('woocommerce_thankyou', 'glami_purchase_code', 10, 1);
function glami_purchase_code($order_id){
$order = new WC_Order($order_id);
// Use $order object to get all the information you need.
```

Comment: is this thee final code to implement it on my functions.php? i don't really know what code to insert in the fields you left.

Comment: I edited my answer a bit more.. there is definitley a work to be done here, answers here can't do the whole work for you. Anyway, I have added the full code for the first and second code requests that you can use on functions.php, the rest you will need to explore and complete.

Comment: i understand that. they told me i need to find the right hooks. but thank you anyway maybe someone can help a bit more.